# How to make images height/width/padding auto scale to fit images in properly

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

What I want to do is have the images on this site change in width and height (they should be equal) between 50-60px. However between them they all need to have a minimum padding of 5px. This can vary depending on the size of the images, this is the case as the two end images need to fit to the edges of the parent div, to align with an image about it. The height/width/padding should all change to ensure the images are still properly aligned when then screen size changes.

If you look at this page you will be able to see what I mean. The images that need to change are the grey squares at the bottom.

http://media.gaigo.org/work2.html

This is my html:

```
<div class="smallImages">
    <div><a href="#item-1"><img src="static/img/smallImage.png"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#item-2"><img src="static/img/smallImage.png"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#item-3"><img src="static/img/smallImage.png"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#item-4"><img src="static/img/smallImage.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

and my css is as follows:

```
smallImages div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.smallImages div img {
    max-width: 60px;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-height: 60px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

Sorry if this seems confusing. Just ask if you need me to explain more.

Comment: It's unclear what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: You are also missing alt, width and height from your img

Comment: @JamieBarker yes i know im struggling to explain it. Basically i want the images at the end of the row to line up with the large image above it

Comment: @DCdaz that is part of my problem! i need them to change as the screen size changes.

Comment: No you dont you need the css to change you still need to define the height and width of an image for rendering. Also you need to make it more clear what it is you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @DCdaz I have tried my best. Look at this page. http://media.gaigo.org/work.html then look at this page http://media.gaigo.org/work2.html as you can see the first one lines up with the large image above, but the second doesnt. However when the page shrinks. The images on the first one shrink also. I want them to stay the same size, like the second one does.

Comment: You mean like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/doqWbB

Comment: if you are just trying to replicate a code that already exists why havent you just looked at the source code.,..

Comment: @Paulie_D Not quite. rather than the images overlapping when they dont fit in the parent div they drop down to a new line below

Comment: @DCdaz because thats my code i need the good bits of the two pages. but im unable to put them together to make it owrk

Comment: Sorry dont understand how you cant just check the source code.

Comment: One page half works and the other half works i need the two halves putting together! And I don't know how to do it. All the source code i wrote. I know what's there I don't know how to put it together!

Comment: All we can suggest if give us a demo (not a link) with the code that doesn't work and let us play with that. Codepen.io is my suggestion.

Comment: @Paulie_D If I had a link to a demo I would be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set percentage widths, however that number percentage is dependent upon the number of images in your row. See this example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box; /* You need this so that heights and widths are inclusive of padding and border */  
}
.container {
  width:400px; /* set this to whatever you like, it should work still */
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.row {
  width:100%;
  padding:0 5px;
}
.row img {
  padding:5px;  
}
.row.one img {
  width:100%;  
}
.row.two img {
  width:50%;  
}
.row.three img {
  width:33.33%;  
}
.row.four img {
  width:25%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row one">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="row two">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="row three">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="row four">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Putting HTML comments between lines means there's no white space between the images.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are after.

Display inline-block wont let the images behave in that manner you need to use table.

You should just check the source code of the site you are working from..

```css
 .row {
   display: table-row;
 }
 .smallImages {
   padding-left: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   display: table;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .smallImages .row div {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 5px;
 }
 .smallImages .row div:first-child {
   padding-left: 0;
 }
 .smallImages .row div img {
   max-width: 100%;
 }
 img {
   border: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="smallImages">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <a href="#item-1">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-2">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-3">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-4">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-5">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-6">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-7">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-8">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-9">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-10">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-11">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#item-12">
        <img src="http://media.gaigo.org/static/img/smallImage.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That only half works. Youve just taken the code from one of the pages i gave you and put it in an answer without considering the fact that i need stuff from the other one too...